# A bug in LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, bidi, bugs

I think the output of the following document is wrong

```
%\the\textdir
\textdir TLT
ab{\textdir TRT ab}\textdir TLT ab

\bye
```

[image]

If I remove at least one of the "unnecessary" `\textdir TLT` I get the correct result.

If I remove the group around `\textdir TRT ab` I get the correct result as well.

Is this a bug in `LuaTeX`? maybe I did not understand LuaTeX's bidirectional typesetting model.

Comment: The last ab appears in the bottom left hand corner of the page, which does catch you by surprise…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is a bug in LuaTeX. Hans Hagen suggested in a [response](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2023-April/006758.html) this might be due to the fact I'm pushing the node in vertical mode, and indeed adding `\leavevmode` solve this example.

But it does not solve a more complex situation. For example

```
\input color

\parskip=20pt

cc{\textdir TRT cc}cc ab\textdir TLT\ \textcolor{green}{end of paragraph}

cc{\textdir TRT cc}cc
ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab\textdir TLT\ \textcolor{red}{end of paragraph}

cc{\textdir TRT cc}cc
ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab
ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab\textdir TLT\ \textcolor{blue}{end of paragraph}


ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab
ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab
cc{\textdir TRT cc}cc
ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab
ab ab ab ab\textdir TLT\ \textcolor{yellow}{end of paragraph}

ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab
ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab
cc{\textdir TRT cc}cc
ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab
ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab
ab ab ab ab\textdir TLT\ \textcolor{yellow}{end of paragraph}


\bye
```

produce the following

[image]

which implies that the bug only occurs only when the two directional
switches are on the same line.

And as David Purton suggested, the missing text appears at the bottom left corner (which I did not notice until he mentioned it). This is the bottom of the page:

[image]

FWIW, I couldn't reproduce this bug in LuaMetaTeX (or with ConTeXt to be more precise).

The bug will probably won't get fixed, for backwards compatibility reasons.